# How to use gpu with Keras on MacOS

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I just want to run my model for deep learning with keras on MacOS
But It's not working

[So I already install plaidml below](https://github.com/plaidml/plaidml/blob/master/docs/install.md#macos)
and I switched 'metal_amd_radeon_pro_560x.0' in plaidml-setup

after that, I added 'os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "plaidml.keras.backend"' in pycharm
but I check gpu activity is low.

and I tried to do another method 'multi_gpu_model' in keras
But I got also error message 'However this machine only has: ['/cpu:0']'

my mac is **2019 macbook pro** with **Radeon Pro 560X 4 GB graphic card**

could you help me for it?

Answer (score 0):

Please follows these steps (assuming you have python already installed),

```
virtualenv plaidml
source plaidml/bin/activate
pip install plaidml-keras plaidbench
```

Choose the accelerator

```
plaidml-setup
```

Set Keras as backend

```
os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "plaidml.keras.backend"
```